# How to attract Cyanobacteria?

Tags: bacteriology, lab-techniques

I would like to attract cyanobacteria in one spot on an object (e.g. cloth,) instead of having it swim in the media. my current method is to pour it on the object in a beaker and wait for some of them to become attached (very pour attachment yield).

Now, I am thinking of making the object emit light. Do you think that the bacteria will swim all the way to the cloth because there are attracted to light?

is there a better method to help the bacteria get attached to the cloth?

Comment: Do you have more details about the experimental setup and constraints? E.g. is your goal to deplete cyanobacteria from a sample? Or to observe the diversity of cyanobacteria in a sample? How pure must the product be (is it a problem if you attract other bugs than cyanobacteria as well)? Can you modify the cyanobacteria, if it's a laboratory strain? And so on... we need as much detail as you can provide to give you an accurate answer!

Answer (score -2):

It might work, many cyanobacteria are reported to be phototaxic. https://www.pnas.org/content/115/52/E12378

Comment: We're looking for longer, self-contained answers. It's important to refer to external resources, but your answer will be better received if you can summarize the key points from a source that are relevant to the question asked so that your answer itself is informative beyond just a link.